# Change an object for a png image on javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I adapted an open source game to fit for my fantasy book series, Eloik.

[This game](http://eloik.com/boomlight_defense.html)

I'd like to replace the blue arc for a png image (about same size).

I know I have to draw an image but how to??

Here's the portion of the code :`

```
       // Shield - Boomlight
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = '#0066cc';
        context.lineWidth = 10;
        context.arc( player.position.x, player.position.y, player.radius, 
        player.angle + 1.6, player.angle - 1.6, true );
        context.stroke();`
```

I tried that following code but... The png image doesn't appears at the right spot and it's not interactive with the game as the arc...`

```
<html>
<body>

<img id="boom" width="176" height="134" src="http://eloik.com/wp/wp-
content/uploads/2017/05/BOOMLIGHT-jeu-bd.png" alt="">

*In the Javascript :

<script>
window.onload = function() {

var image = new Image();
image.src="http://eloik.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/BOOMLIGHT-jeu-
bd.png";
context.beginPath();
context.drawImage(image, 10, 10);   
}
</script>

</body>
</html> `
```

So now, what's wrong ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to use `drawImage`, we need to load it. You can do it like this:

```
/* core.js: line 57 */
// Create a handle for the image
var shieldImage;

/* core.js: line 133 */
// Create a new image
shieldImage = new Image();
// When it's loaded, execute animate
shieldImage.onload = animate;
// Set the src
shieldImage.src = "http://eloik.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/BOOMLIGHT-jeu-bd.png";
```

This way, the `animate` function will only be called once the image has loaded. Then, in order to position your image and rotate it, you can do this:

```
/* core.js: line 420 */
// Set the origin of the canvas on the player position
context.translate(player.position.x, player.position.y);
// Rotate the canvas
context.rotate(player.angle + Math.PI + .2);
// Draw the shield
context.drawImage(shieldImage, -player.radius, -player.radius, player.radius*1.5, player.radius*2.3);
// Rotate the canvas back
context.rotate(-player.angle - Math.PI - .2);
// Reset the initial origin of the canvas
context.translate(-player.position.x, -player.position.y);
```

Since we cannot rotate the image itself, we use this trick, which consists in rotating the canvas, drawing, and reverting the rotation of the canvas. We also translate it in order to have the rotation axis on the player position.

You'll also notice I added some numbers in there. That's because your shield image is not a perfect circle. I distorted it so that it does not look weird with the current collision system (which is based on a circle). If you want to keep the oval shape of the image, you'll need to make more serious changes to the rest of the code so that collisions apply to that shape.

And that's it, your blue arc is replaced with your PNG image ([Updated JS here](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/MP9qsiT9))

*PS: You have a cool last name ! - same as mine*

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOW !!!! Reaaaaaly a big thanks !! It worked perfectly and I understood what you've done. 

If we have the same last name... Tu parles aussi français ? Merci beaucoup donc ! :)

Comment: @SébastienSelLévesque You're welcome, content d'avoir pu t'aider :)